# Pushing entries into an array in a nested loop

Tags: javascript

My code:

```js
function zeroArray() {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
        newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray
}

console.log(zeroArray())
```

From my perspective, its look like the result  will be :

```
[[ 0, 0 ],[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]]
```

but when the code run in the console it shows this, why is that?

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Comment: You push *the same* array multiple times. It's not *copies* but literally references to the same `row` array multiple times inside `newArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function zeroArray() {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row); // <== Problematic line
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

The problem is when you push `row` array into `newArray`, it doesn't actually push the values into it; it pushes the *pointer* to that array, which means after updating `row` array, if you push it again, it will push the same value to `newArray`.

Posted the illustration for detailed explanation:

[image]

The solution is as some other people noted, re-creating the array each time instead of using the same variable. For example, the solution could be:

```
function zeroArray() {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row); // <== Problematic line
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: please also see the proposed solution that I just updated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an unexpected instance of mutating an object. In this case, you're pushing the same `row` multiple times, then updating it (resulting in that it updates the three instances of it that end up in `newArray`). If you instead use something like `newArray.push(row.slice())`, the output will be as you expect.